# How to Subdivide Keyframe Curves in Graph Editor (Create Keyframes for Every Frame)

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor, timeline

Is there a way to automatically create/insert a keyframe for every frame on the timeline for an animated object?

In other words, I have an object that moves from point A to point B, with two keyframes at the beginning and end of my timeline.  What I want to do is somehow bake the motion into a keyframe for every frame, so that I can mess with each one individually and give my motion a glitchy effect.

Is there an easy way to do this?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/s9lql5le88e6y768sjb75/Create-Keyframes-How.blend?rlkey=d52wpf78lznleb68h2k3wkafq&dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Can you press this, and play the animation until the end? https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2yie.jpg

Comment: @gottastayhighallthetime Auto Keyframing?  What would that do?  Do you mean to use auto-keyframes and move the frame manually during playback?  This is certainly a technique people use for creating jerky camera movements, but that's not what I was looking for. Thanks though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in graph editor select your channel, then key-> density -> sample keyframes

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!!